# DFP Async Mime Type Issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've setup Google's asynchronous DFP tags locally, but I'm getting this message intermittently in my console:

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://ib.adnxs.com/a_usersync?cbfn=ANX_async_load".

When this message appears, ads do not. Is it a local/dev environment issue only?

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, you're loading Javascript from that URL, but the URL is returning (or claiming to return) HTML instead.

If the HTML looks like Javascript, most browsers will run it anyway, so that URL is probably giving you an error.
Look at the network tab to see what's going on.